# Getting undefined variables in view after adding a gate route

Tags: laravel

I have an admin dashboard in my project that displays all the data I want it to display (`Users, books, reviews, comments`) but when I tried to add a gate to restrict users that doesn't have the `isAdmin` value set to `1` my entire view crashes and all my variables go undefined.

Here is the controller I'm working with

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use App\Book;
use App\Review;
use App\Comment;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;


class AdminsController extends Controller
{
    public function admin()
    {
        if (Gate::allows('admins', auth()->user())) {
            return view('admin.dashboard');
        }
        return 'Unauthorized entry';
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function index()
    {   
        $users = User::all();
        $books = Book::all();
        $reviews = Review::all();
        $comments = Comment::all();


        return view('admin.dashboard', compact('users' ,'books', 'reviews', 'comments'));


    }
```

The gate im using is defined in AuthServiceProvider and looks like this

```
Gate::define('admins', function ($user) {
      if($user->isAdmin == 1)
      {
        return true;
      }
        return false;
});
```

Here are my two routes for that view

```
// Admin
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminsController');
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminsController@admin')->name('admin');
```

Whenever I remove the admin route all my variables seems to work without problems. I'm also achieving what I want with this code whenever a user is not an admin. The error only occurs whenever an admin access the admin dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the data along with the view in the admin() method.

Update:

```
public function admin()
    {
        if (Gate::allows('admins', auth()->user())) {
            return view('admin.dashboard');
        }
        return 'Unauthorized entry';
    }
```

to:

```
public function admin()
    {
        if (Gate::allows('admins', auth()->user())) {
            return view('admin.dashboard', compact('users' ,'books', 'reviews', 'comments'));
        }
        return 'Unauthorized entry';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my variable issue.